# Moving Ranges in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to be able to tell if a certain range of 20 cells has content, if so then move to the next 20 cells directly in the range below. Example(Sue-do): If Range(A1-B10) has items, then move to range (A11-B20). There can only be a max of 20 ranges(so 400 cells). I have code that populates these cells, but it overwrites if more than 1 item is chose to collect data from.

Comment: Record yourself inserting the cells and go from there.

Comment: "I have code that populates these cells" - you're more likely to get help if you include your existing code.

Comment: Jeeped is suggesting you use Macro Recorder function in the Developer Tab. Start recording, do manually the steps you want your script to do. Then you can review the code pressing Alt + F11 and adapt the code to accomplish in more general way what you want. Hope this helps

Comment: Okay but recording a macro won't help because the range of cells will change. And the code I have currently wouldn't help because i have the range hard coded in so there would be nothing of use there. My guess is to create an array of ranges, then select that range depending on the incoming data (which is just a document number). Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that:

```
dim Emptiness as boolean
dim MyRange as range, Cell1 as range
dim i as integer, j as integer

set myrange=range("A1:B10")

for i=0 to 19
    j=10*i
    set myrange=myrange.offset(j,0)
    Emptiness=true
    for each cell1 in myrange
        if isempty(cell1)=false then
            emptiness=false
            exit for
        else
            emptiness=true
        endif
    next cell1

    if emptiness=true then
        'your code that populates
    endif

next i
```

Comment: I wrote it fast so there might be some mistakes. If errors are returned please specify which line of the code and what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1:B20") <--| change "MySheet" with your actual sheet name and "A1:B20" with your actual "initial" range
        For i = 0 To 19
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Offset(i * 20)) = 0 Then
                ' code to populate
                ' remember that ".Offset(i * 20)" will return the found 20-rows-2-columns range with no data
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MattCucco: did you get through it?